# mingw 64-bit build of gdb crashes before launching program

Tags: crash, gdb, mingw-w64

I have installed msys2 and mingw64 and I am using it for programming purposes. I used Pacman to install GCCc which comes with GDB. I am having difficulty running GDB. I get the following error in two programs I am running:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\hwselector.exe
warning: cYgFFFFFFFF 18023CC60 0
[New Thread 18816.0x3cc0]
[New Thread 18816.0x4284]
[New Thread 18816.0x4d98]
Number of Problems: warning: cYgstd 0xffffcb90 d 3
[Thread 18816.0x3cc0 exited with code 0]
[Thread 18816.0x4e88 exited with code 0]
[Thread 18816.0x4d98 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 18816) exited normally]
```

I do not know GDB internals enough to fix this problem. Does anyone know why this is happening? I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit edition. GDB and GCC are their respective 64 bit versions (I assume) and the latest version of MSYS64

Answer (score 1):

If you used pacman -S gcc or similar to install gcc, that is not the right gcc to use. Better delete it and use `pacboy -S gcc`.

Also, gcc does not come with gdb. Make sure you install it separately (`pacboy -S gdb`), I believe you may accidentally be using a cygwin gdb.

Comment: Thank you very much @Christian B. That seems to do the trick. But now msys cannot find gdb which is located in /usr/bin. I checked the PATH variable and it is added there! This msys is very odd. But I am sure I can figure it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Open your executable with DependancyWalker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for the same version (x86 / x64) and check if there are any missing dependancy DLLs.

In many cases where GDB couldn't give me information, DependancyWalker helped me in detecting the fact that DLLs were missing, or even loaded from the wrong location.